# Datatables buttons not showing with Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, datatables, hadoop-yarn

I am using datatables with Bootstrap 4 and I want to use the buttons extension to export the table data. However, the buttons are not showing up on the page and there are no errors in the console. Here are my import statements:

```
import 'datatables.net-bs4';
import 'datatables.net-buttons-bs4';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5';
import 'datatables.net-select-bs4';
import $ from 'jquery';
```

And here is my table initialization:

```
const table = $table.DataTable({
    columns: columns,
    deferRender: true,
    buttons: ['csv'],
    dom:
        "<'row'<'col'l><'col text-right'<'d-inline-block mr-2'B><'d-inline-block'f>>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
    language: language(`./datatables.${document.documentElement.lang}.yaml`),
    paging: true,
    select: select,
});
```

I have tried different versions of datatables and jQuery, but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was that the style plugins for Bootstrap 4 were requesting an older version of datatables as a dependency. Yarn installed two versions of datatables and the plugins were running in the older version, which I was not using.

To fix this, I had to add a resolution field in my package.json file to force yarn to use a single version of datatables for all dependencies. Like this:

```
"resolutions": {
  "datatables.net": "1.10.22"
}
```

After that, I ran yarn install again and the buttons showed up correctly. Hope this helps someone else.